# My airflow DAG and operator are not doing what I expected

Tags: airflow

edit: I figured out my problem. I didn't understand the different between triggering a run and it running immediately and keeping it on and letting it do its job. The code is fine.

I wrote this simple program to figure out airflow. On the hour it is supposed to print to a file "hello world", but it's doing it immediately. Does someone see where I am going wrong?

```
def print_hello():
    f = open('helloword.txt','a')
    f.write( 'Hello World!')
    f.close()

dag = DAG('hello_world', description='Simple tutorial DAG', schedule_interval='@hourly',
          start_date=datetime(2018, 5, 31), catchup=False)


hello_operator = PythonOperator(task_id='hello_task', python_callable=print_hello, dag=dag)
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer below.  Feel free to vote for it as well if you found it helpful.  I'm also happy to edit it if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The start date is `2018-05-31` and the schedule interval is `@hourly`, so the execution date for the first run would normally be `2018-05-31T00:00:00` with a start date >= ~`2018-05-31T01:00:00`.

In this case, you have set catchup to false, so instead only the most recent DAG run will be created.  I would expect that DAG run created to be `2018-05-31T21:00:00` right now.

The current UTC time is `2018-05-31T22:00:00` right now.  Since the start date timestamp `2018-05-31T00:00:00` is in the past, the Airflow scheduler will schedule and start the task immediately.

You can delete the DAG runs and task instances and then change the start date to `2018-06-01` if you want it to start fresh tomorrow.  It would not run immediately in this case if you choose a start date in the future.

You can find a bit more info about how the scheduler works here:

- [Airflow Wiki > Scheduler Basics](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Scheduler+Basics)
- [Airflow Docs > Scheduling & Triggers > To Keep in Mind](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#to-keep-in-mind)

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine to me. Are you seeing some lines appended to the file if you put your DAG off?

I think what you're seeing is the backfill executions running. You put your start date today, implicitly at midnight. Airflow will therefore catch up and fire up these DAG runs first before eventually running your task every hour.

Comment: actually my backfill is set to false but yes my code is fine. thank you!